# How to assign the return value of command to other variable using Expect

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I have the following scenario which is working fine on command line

```
value=`cat /root/abc`
echo $value
```

which is printing the content of the file abc

now same I want to perform using Expect

I did as follow

```
send "value=`cat /root/abc`\r"
```

now I want to capture the value in some variable as follow

```
set A_Value = $value
```

but getting error  `can't read "value": no such variable`

I am very new to `expect` and trying it first time, So could anyone please let me know how to achieve the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that expect is just a robot typing the keys for you. Expect does not have any special insight into the inner workings of the process it is automating.

You are stuck doing something like this: capture the output excluding the command you sent and the prompt:

```
send "echo \"\$value\"\r"
expect -re "echo \[^\r]+\r\n(.*)\r\n$prmpt $"
set file_contents $expect_out(1,string)
```

Comment: Thanks for response , but I am getting can't read "expect_out(1,string)": no such element in array
    while executing